# WSDL auto generated with a complex node does not match service request

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wsdl, asmx

I have this WSDL,

```
     <s:element name="IncidentCreated">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="IncidentCreatedStc" type="tns:IncidentCreatedStc" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="IncidentCreatedStc">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CreationDate" type="s:dateTime" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DangerFlag" nillable="true" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DeadDeviceAlias" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
```

And I auto generate the service reference (WSDL) in c#  and it look like this:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="ENMAC/TCS" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="ENMAC/TCS" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="ENMAC/TCS">
<s:element name="IncidentCreated">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CreationDate" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DangerFlag" nillable="true" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DeadDeviceAlias" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

The node IncidentCreatedStc never got created, what I actually wouldn't think it would anyway, the problem is that when I receive the XML from the service it look like

```
<IncidentCreated>
    <IncidentCreatedStr>
        <CreationDate></CreationDate>
        <DangerFlag></DangerFlag>
        <DeadDeviceAlias></DeadDeviceAlias>
    </IncidentCreatedStr>
</IncidentCreated>
```

My question is how do I make my soap service conform to this last format?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Exactly how did you "auto generate" this WSDL? How did you create your classes based on the original WSDL?

Comment: I use "add service reference" in c# and pointed to the WSDL i received, I can't access the service from my machine to point the it.

Comment: I'll update the service to WCF as soon as I can, unfortunately when I first developed the app I just based it in a old service I find here. But thank you for the hint.